# ms filter gradient and background image

Tags: background-image, gradient

Is there any way (other than using another element) to get a background image to sit on top of a gradient in IE8 and IE9? In the following example the gradient always overrides the background image. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">   

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>ms filter gradient and background image</title>

<style type="text/css">
div {
width:500px;
height:500px;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient (GradientType=0, startColorstr=red, endColorstr=blue)";
background:url('my-image.gif') no-repeat;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div></div>

</body>

</html>
```